# Complex? Eplode() variable I can't figure out

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I have a variable, let's call it `$var` that echoes out something like:

`32-Widgets: 18,28-Widgets: 24,57-Widgets: 45,44-Widgets: 24,55-Widgets: 45`

The variable is created from a combination of a form submission and jQuery Sortables (which is why everything ends up in one variable, not two). The order is very important.

What I'd like to end up with is two variables (can be arrays) that would be:

```
$newVar1 = 32,18,24,45,24
$newVar2 = Widgets: 18,Widgets: 24,Widgets: 45,Widgets: 24,Widgets: 45
```

I started by:

`$newVars = explode(",",$var);`

But I'm at a loss of where to go from there. I've tried a variety of statements such as:

```
foreach ($newVars as $newVar) :
    //Various explode() functions tried here.
endforeach;
```

If anybody has any idea what I'm missing I would certainly appreciate the help.

Thank you,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but it'll do the trick.

```
<?php

$str = "32-Widgets: 18,28-Widgets: 24,57-Widgets: 45,44-Widgets: 24,55-Widgets: 45";

$entries = explode(",", $str);
$parts1 = array();
$parts2 = array();

foreach ($entries as $e)
{
    $temp = explode("-", $e);
    $parts1[] = $temp[0];
    $parts2[] = $temp[1];
}

print_r($parts1);
print_r($parts2);

?>
```

Running example: http://ideone.com/KkL06f

Comment: On a side note, I'd probably use regular expressions if you know it's always going to be in a set format.  For example: `/(\d+)-(Widgets: \d+)/i`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
public function just_a_test() {
    $var = "32-Widgets: 18,28-Widgets: 24,57-Widgets: 45,44-Widgets: 24,55-Widgets: 45";
    $vars = explode(',', $var);
    $partsA = $partsB = array();
    foreach ($vars as $aVar) {
        preg_match('/^(\d+)-(Widgets: \d+)$/i', $aVar, $parts);
        $partsA []= $parts[0];
        $partsB []= $parts[1];
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($partsA);
    print_r($partsB);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

You could easily end up with output like yours by calling the implode() with each array.